# How to: Onclick buttons and text area scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This community has been really helpful for a beginner like me to continue the projects that I've been doing, and I thank you all for that. However, I am going to try my luck again today.

I have a problem I cannot solve on my own, and cannot really search the web for the specific because I do not know what to are the magic words that I need. Enough with the introduction, let me proceed to my question.

Okay, just a few more. I am creating a somewhat Text/HTML Editor in a local html file that I can share with my team and which will be very useful for a content editor like us so that we can build XML tags from scratch (I will replace the HTML tags which I'll show in a while) once I have all the resources and codes that I will need.

Here is a quick glance as to how it looks like:

[image]

So, to explain it briefly, my question is mainly about 2 things and a few minor ones, and please do tell me wherever I am wrong and I am open for any suggestions.

1) When I click the

tag, it should appear where my cursor is currently clicked on and not below all the texts above it. But right now, that is what is happening. I know there is something missing with my script and that's why. Therefore can I please ask for a suggestion or a guidance that is a easily understandable by a beginner? Pardon me for being so demanding here.

2) When I click on a certain tag button above the editor, can it appear in a **bold** format like **this** instead of this `<b>this</b>`?

I've read somewhere that the box below is a text area and wouldn't allow formatting like Bold, Italics, and Underline, however, is there a way to do that with some HTML, CSS, and JS? (cause that's the only languages that I can somehow understand, albeit a newbie.)

Anyway, I need to at least be able to embolden some tags like  so that is easily recognizable when the content are all over the place. If it's not possible, can you please suggest to me a language that I should learn or at least point me to some direction to go to?

If it's still not possible to do that, at least, is there a way to highlight the tags?

Now for some minor questions...

3) I believe there is a specific `enter like <br/> in HTML` or `space like (&nbsp;) in HTML`for javascript? If my guess is correct, is it something like `\n`?

4) Lastly for now, do I need to merge all the different scripts that I have in a single `<script></script>` tag or its ok to separate them depending on their function?

I am both thankful and sorry for such a long post and question. I do hope I can make it much more concise but I am really clueless right now as to how to ask my questions.

By the way, I will attach the complete code that I currently, (cause I'm not sure what is necessary to crop). So thank you all once again. I hope I get to pass this trial!

```
<html>
<center><title>EDEN Editor</title></center>
<div align="center">
<h1>EDEN Editor</h1>
</div>
<hr>
<br/>
<style>
.button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #e5e59b;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.button:hover {background-color: #f5f5d8}

.button:active {
  background-color: #e5e59b;
  transform: translateY(1px);
}
</style>
<script language="JavaScript">

helpstat = false;
stprompt = false;
basic = true;

function thelp(swtch){
        if (swtch == 1){
                basic = false;
                stprompt = false;
                helpstat = true;
        }
        else if (swtch == 0) {
                helpstat = false;
                stprompt = false;
                basic = true;
        }
        else if (swtch == 2) {
                helpstat = false;
                basic = false;
                stprompt = true;
        }
}

function treset(){
        if (helpstat){
                alert("Clears the current editor.");
        }
        else {
        clear = prompt("Are you sure? (y/n)",'');
        clear = clear.toLowerCase();
        if(clear == 'y') {
                document.editor.reset();
                document.editor.value = "";
        }
        }
}       

function start(){
        if (helpstat){
                alert("Elements that appear at the beginning of the document, including TITLE.");
        }
        else if (basic) {
        document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "<html>\n<head>\n<title></title>\n</head>\n<body>\n";
        }
        else if (stprompt) {
                for(;;){
                        twrite = prompt("Title?",'');
                        if (twrite != "" && twrite != null){
                                break;
                        }
                        else {
                                prompt("You must enter a title.",'Ok, sorry.');
                        }
                }
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "<html>\n<head>\n<title>" + twrite + "</title>\n</head>\n<body ";

                twrite = prompt("Background color? (blank if none)",'');        
                if (twrite != "" && twrite != null){
                        twrite = '"' + twrite + '"';
                        document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "bgcolor=" + twrite + " ";
                }

                twrite = prompt("Background image? (blank if none)",'');                
                if (twrite != "" && twrite != null){
                        twrite = '"' + twrite + '"';
                        document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "background=" + twrite + " ";
                }

                twrite = prompt("Text color? (blank if none)",'');
                if (twrite != "" && twrite != null){
                        twrite = '"' + twrite + '"';
                        document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "text=" + twrite + " ";
                }

                twrite = prompt("Link color? (blank if none)",'');              
                if (twrite != "" && twrite != null){
                        twrite = '"' + twrite + '"';
                        document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "link=" + twrite + " ";
                }

                twrite = prompt("Visited link color? (blank if none)",'');              
                if (twrite != "" && twrite != null){
                        twrite = '"' + twrite + '"';            
                        document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "vlink=" + twrite + " ";
                }

                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + ">\n";
        }
}

function end(){
        if (helpstat){
                alert("Adds the the final elements to a document.");
        }
        else {
        document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "\n</body>\n</html>\n";  
        }
}

function preview(){
        if (helpstat) {
                alert("Preview/save the document.");
        }
        else {
                temp = document.editor.area.value;
                preWindow= open("", "preWindow","status=no,toolbar=n,menubar=y");
                preWindow.document.open();
                preWindow.document.write(temp);
                preWindow.document.close();
        }
}

function bold() {
        if (helpstat) {
                alert("Bold text.");
        }
        else if (basic) {
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "<b></b>";
        }
        else if (stprompt) {
                twrite = prompt("Text?",'');
                if (twrite != null && twrite != ""){
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "<b>" + twrite + "</b>";
                }
        }
}

function italic() {
        if (helpstat) {
                alert("Italicizes text.");
        }
        else if (basic) {
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "<i></i>";
        }
        else if (stprompt) {
                twrite = prompt("Text?",'');
                if (twrite != null && twrite != ""){
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "<i>" + twrite + "</i>";
                }
        }
}

function underline(){
        if (helpstat) {
                alert("Underlines text.");
        }
        else if (basic) {
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "<u></u>";
        }
        else if (stprompt) {
                twrite = prompt("Text?",'');
                if (twrite != null && twrite != ""){
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "<u>" + twrite + "</u>";
                }
        }
}

function pre(){
        if (helpstat) {
                alert("Sets text as preformatted.");
        }
        else if (basic) {
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "<pre></pre>";
        }
        else if (stprompt) {
                twrite = prompt("Text?",'');
                if (twrite != null && twrite != ""){
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "<pre>" + twrite + "</pre>";
                }
        }
}

function center(){
        if (helpstat) {
                alert("Centers text.");
        }
        else if (basic) {
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "<StatCode Law Text>\n\n\n\n</Statcode> Random123\n";
        }
        else if (stprompt) {
                twrite = prompt("Text?",'');
                if (twrite != null && twrite != ""){
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "<center>" + twrite + "</center>";
                }
        }
}

function hbar(){
        if (helpstat) {
                alert("Creates a horizontal bar.");
        }
        else {
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "<hr>\n";
        }
}

function lbreak(){
        if (helpstat) {
                alert("Makes a new line, the equivalent of return or enter.");
        }
        else {
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "<br />\n";
        }
}

function pbreak(){
        if (helpstat) {
                alert("Makes two new lines, the equivalent of two returns or enters.");
        }
        else {
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "<p>\n";
        }
}

function image(){
        if (helpstat) {
                alert("Inserts an image.");
        }
        else if (basic) {
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + '<img src=""></img>\n';
        }
        else if (stprompt) {
                twrite = prompt("Image location?",'');
                if (twrite != null && twrite != ""){
                twrite = '"' + twrite + '"';
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + '<img src=' + twrite + '>\n';
                }
        }
}

function aleft(){
        if (helpstat) {
                alert("Inserts an image with align left.");
        }
        else if (basic) {
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + '<img src="" align=left></img>\n';
        }
        else if (stprompt){
                twrite = prompt("Image location?",'');
                if (twrite != null && twrite != ""){
                twrite = '"' + twrite + '"';
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + '<img src=' + twrite + ' align=left>\n';
                }
        }
}

function aright(){
        if (helpstat) {
                alert("Inserts an image with align right.");
        }
        else if (basic) {
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + '<img src="" align=right></img>\n';
        }
        else if (stprompt) {
                twrite = prompt("Image location?",'');
                if (twrite != null && twrite != ""){
                twrite = '"' + twrite + '"';
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + '<img src=' + twrite + ' align=right></img>\n';
                }
        }
}

function atop(){
        if (helpstat) {
                alert("Inserts an image with align top.");
        }
        else if (basic) {
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + 'how to add tables in sites\n';
        }
        else if (stprompt) {
                twrite = prompt("Image location?",'');
                if (twrite != null && twrite != ""){
                twrite = '"' + twrite + '"';
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + '<img src=' + twrite + ' align=top></img>\n';
                }
        }
}

function amid(){
        if (helpstat) {
                alert("Inserts an image with align middle.");
        }
        else if (basic) {
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + '<img src="" align=middle></img>\n';
        }
        else if (stprompt) {
                twrite = prompt("Image location?",'');
                if (twrite != null && twrite != ""){
                twrite = '"' + twrite + '"';
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + '<img src=' + twrite + ' align=middle></img>\n';
                }
        }
}

function abottom(){
        if (helpstat) {
                alert("Inserts an image with align bottom.");
        }
        else if (basic) {
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + '<img src="" align=bottom></img>\n';
        }
        else if (stprompt) {
                twrite = prompt("Image location?",'');
                if (twrite != null && twrite != ""){
                twrite = '"' + twrite + '"';
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + '<img src=' + twrite + ' align=bottom></img>\n';
                }
        }
}

function head1(){
        if (helpstat) {
                alert("Creates a header, size 1 (largest size).");
        }
        else if (basic) {
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "<h1></h1>\n";
        }
        else if (stprompt) {
                twrite = prompt("Text?",'');
                if (twrite != null && twrite != ""){
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "<h1>" + twrite + "</h1>\n";
                }
        }
}

function head2(){
        if (helpstat) {
                alert("Creates a header, size 2 (slightly smaller than 1).");
        }
        else if (basic) {
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "<h2></h2>\n";
        }
        else if (stprompt) {
                twrite = prompt("Text?",'');
                if (twrite != null && twrite != ""){
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "<h2>" + twrite + "</h2>\n";
                }
        }
}

function head3(){
        if (helpstat) {
                alert("Creates a header, size 3 (slightly smaller than 2).");
        }
        else if (basic) {
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "<h3></h3>\n";
        }
        else if (stprompt) {
                twrite = prompt("Text?",'');
                if (twrite != null && twrite != ""){
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "<h3>" + twrite + "</h3>\n";
                }
        }
}

function head4(){
        if (helpstat) {
                alert("Creates a header, size 4 (slightly smaller than 3).");
        }
        else if (basic) {
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "<h4></h4>\n";
        }
        else if (stprompt) {
                twrite = prompt("Text?",'');
                if (twrite != null && twrite != ""){
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "<h4>" + twrite + "</h4>\n";
                }
        }
}

function head5(){
        if (helpstat) {
                alert("Creates a header, size 5 (slightly smaller than 4).");
        }
        else if (basic) {
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "<h5></h5>\n";
        }
        else if (stprompt) {
                twrite = prompt("Text?",'');
                if (twrite != null && twrite != ""){
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "<h5>" + twrite + "</h5>\n";
                }
        }
}

function head6(){
        if (helpstat) {
                alert("Creates a header, size 6 (smallest size).");
        }
        else if (basic) {
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "<h6></h6>\n";
        }
        else if (stprompt) {
                twrite = prompt("Text?",'');
                if (twrite != null && twrite != ""){
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "<h6>" + twrite + "</h6>\n";
                }
        }
}

function linkopen(){
        if (helpstat) {
                alert("Begins a link.");
        }
        else if (basic) {
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + '<a href=""></a>';
        }
        else if (stprompt) {
                twrite = prompt("File location?",'');
                if (twrite != null && twrite != ""){
                twrite = '"' + twrite + '"';
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + '<a href=' + twrite + '>';
                for(;;){
                        twrite = prompt("Text?",'');
                        if (twrite != "" && twrite != null){
                                break;
                        }
                        else {
                                prompt("You must enter the link text.",'Ok, sorry.');
                        }
                        }
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + twrite + '</a>\n';
                        }
        }
}

function linktext(){
        if (helpstat) {
                alert("Inserts the text for a link.");
        }
        else if (basic) {
                for(;;){
                        twrite = prompt("Text?",'');
                        if (twrite != "" && twrite != null){
                                break;
                        }
                        else {
                                prompt("You must enter the link text.",'Ok, sorry.');
                        }
                }
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + twrite + '\n';
        }
        else if (stprompt) {
                alert("Not used in prompt mode.");
        }
}

function linkclose(){
        if (helpstat) {
                alert("Closes a link.");
        }
        else if (basic) {
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "</a>\n";
        }
        else if (stprompt) {
                alert("Not used in prompt mode.");
        }
}

function anchor(){
        if (helpstat) {
                alert("Sets an anchor (e.g. #here).");
        }
        else if (basic) {
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + '<a name=""></a>\n';
        }
        else if (stprompt) {
                twrite = prompt("Anchor name?",'');
                if (twrite != null && twrite != ""){
                twrite = '"' + twrite + '"';
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + '<a name=' + twrite + '>\n';
                }
        }
}

function orderopen(){
        if (helpstat) {
                alert("Starts an ordered list.");
        }
        else if (basic) {
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "<ol></ol>\n";
        }
        else if (stprompt) {
                for(i=1;;i++){
                        twrite = prompt("Item " + i + "? (Blank entry stops.)",'');
                        if (twrite == "" || twrite == null){
                                break;
                        }
                        if (i == 1){
                                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "<ol>\n";
                                okeydokey = 1;
                        }
                        document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "<li>" + twrite + "\n";
                }
                if (okeydokey) {
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "</ol>\n";
                }
        }
}

function li(){
        if (helpstat) {
                alert("Creates an item in a list.");
        }
        else if (basic) {
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "<li>";
        }
        else if (stprompt) {
                alert("Not used in prompt mode.");
        }
}

function orderclose(){
        if (helpstat) {
                alert("Closes an ordered list.");
        }
        else if (basic) {
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "</ol>\n";
        }
        else if (stprompt) {
                alert("Not used in prompt mode.");
        }
}

function unorderopen(){
        if (helpstat) {
                alert("Starts an unordered list.");
        }
        else if (basic) {
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "<ul></ul>";
        }
        else if (stprompt) {
                for(i=1;;i++){
                        twrite = prompt("Item " + i + "? (Blank entry stops.)",'');
                        if (twrite == "" || twrite == null){
                                break;
                        }
                        if (i == 1){
                                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "<ul>\n";
                                okeydokey = 1;
                        }
                        document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "<li>" + twrite + "\n";
                }
                if (okeydokey) {
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "</ul>\n";
                }
        }
}

function unorderclose(){
        if (helpstat) {
                alert("Closes an unordered list.");
        }
        else if (basic) {
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "</ul>\n";
        }
        else if (stprompt) {
                alert("Not used in prompt mode.");
        }
}

function defopen(){
        if (helpstat) {
                alert("Starts a definition list.");
        }
        else if (basic) {
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "<dl>";
        }
        else if (stprompt) {
                for(i=1;;i++){
                        twrite = prompt("Term " + i + "? (Blank entry stops.)",'');
                        if (twrite == "" || twrite == null){
                                break;
                        }
                        if (i == 1) {
                                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "<dl>\n";
                                okeydokey = 1;
                        }
                        document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "<dt>" + twrite + "</dt>\n";
                        twrite = prompt("Definition" + i + "? (Blank entry stops.)",'');
                        if (twrite == "" || twrite == null){
                                break;
                        }
                        document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "<dd>" + twrite + "<dd>\n";
                }
                if (okeydokey){
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "</dl>\n";
                }
        }
}

function defterm(){
        if (helpstat) {
                alert("Creates the term in a definition.");
        }
        else if (basic) {
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "<dt>";
        }
        else if (stprompt) {
                alert("Not used in prompt mode.");
        }
}

function define(){
        if (helpstat) {
                alert("Creates the definition.");
        }
        else if (basic) {
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "<dd>";
        }
        else if (stprompt) {
                alert("Not used in prompt mode.");
        }
}

function defclose(){    
        if (helpstat) {
                alert("Closes a defeinition list.");
        }
        else if (basic) {
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "</dt>";
        }
        else if (stprompt) {
                alert("Not used in prompt mode.");
        }
}

function font(){
        if (helpstat) {
                alert("Sets the font.");
        }
        else if (basic) {
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + '';
        }
        else if (stprompt) {
                twrite = prompt("Font?",'');
                if (twrite != null && twrite != "") {
                twrite = '"' + twrite + '"';
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + '';
                }
        }
}

function fontcolor(){
        if (helpstat) {
                alert("Sets the font color.");
        }
        else if (basic) {
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + '';
        }
        else if (stprompt) {
                twrite = prompt("Color? (hex or name)",'');
                if (twrite != null && twrite != "") {
                twrite = '"' + twrite + '"';
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + '';
        }

}
function formtr(){
        if (helpstat) {
                alert("Creates a table row.");
        }
        else if (basic) {
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "<tr></tr>";
        }
        else if (stprompt) {
                alert("Not used in prompt mode.");
        }
}
function formtd(){
        if (helpstat) {
                alert("Creates a standard table cell.");
        }
        else if (basic) {
                document.editor.area.value = document.editor.area.value + "<td></td>";
        }
        else if (stprompt) {
                alert("Not used in prompt mode.");
        }
}
</script>

<form name="editor">
<center>
<table border=1>
<td align=center>
<b>Choose Mode:</b><br>
<input type="radio" name="mode" value="help"onClick="thelp(1)">Guide
<input type="radio" name="mode" value="prompt" onClick="thelp(2)">Prompt
<input type="radio" name="mode" value="basic" checked onClick="thelp(0)">Write
</td>
</table>
<br>
<table border=1>
<tr>
<td align=center>
<input type="button" value="Preview" onClick="preview()">
<input type="button" value=" Start " onClick="start()">
<input type="button" value="  End  " onClick="end()">
<input type="button" value="<img>" onClick="image()">
<input type="button" value="<L>"onClick="aleft()">
<input type="button" value="<R>" onClick="aright()">
<input type="button" value="<T>" onClick="atop()">
<input type="button" value="<M>" onClick="amid()">
<input type="button" value="<B>" onClick="abottom()">
<input type="button" value="Reset" onClick="treset()">
</td>
</tr>
<td>
<input type="button" value="B" onClick="bold()">
<input type="button" value="I" onClick="italic()">
<input type="button" value="U" onClick="underline()">
<input type="button" value="C" onClick="center()">
<input type="button" value="<p>" onClick="pbreak()">
<input type="button" value="<br>" onClick="lbreak()">
<input type="button" value="<hr>" onClick="hbar()">
<input type="button" value="<pre>" onClick="pre()">
<input type="button" value="h1" onClick="head1()">
<input type="button" value="h2" onClick="head2()">
<input type="button" value="h3" onClick="head3()">
<input type="button" value="h4" onClick="head4()">
<input type="button" value="h5" onClick="head5()">
<input type="button" value="h6" onClick="head6()">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
<textarea name="area" rows=50 cols=71 wrap=physical>
</textarea>
<br>
<br>
</td>
</table>
</center>

<body>



</body>
</form>
```

Comment: https://www.mynotepaper.com/how-to-add-wysiwyg-tinymce-to-any-textarea

Comment: Hi @bestinamir that is really amazing! Although can I customize a button, for example, I click P buttton (which I will add), it will generate a "<p></p>"?

Comment: My knowledge in this area is limited. Please ask like this in a new question and tag it tinymce. You can add a link to this question for reference.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly answering your questions to give you a way to follow:

**1)** If you are going to use `<textarea>`, you can solve it using `selectionStart`
But if you are going to use contenteditable set to true in a different tag, I'd recommend you to take a look at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/isLishude/6ccd1fbf42d1eaac667d6873e7b134f8) (that works for both `<textarea>` and editable elements).

**2)** You can solve it using `contenteditable` attribute. So you don't have to use a `<textarea>` element, but a `<div>`, for example.

```
<div contenteditable="true">editable text</div>
```

Then you can use formats such as **bold** or *italic*.

**3)** Yes, in order to create new lines, you can use `\n` when appending text. When formatting is allowed, `<br>` should make it when appending HTML format.

**4)** Although merging JavaScript files is better for performance, it can also be bad for unnecessarily cluttering code. So it's a question of organization. For that there are some tools like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [gulp](https://gulpjs.com/), that do this job automatically for you according to the configuration you choose. So, for example, your scripts can merge only to the final stage, while in the development environment it continues the way you wrote it so you can work properly.

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your time, I'm checking now what to do. Thanks!!